# cant remove a selection list

Tags: php, html

When run the code bellow shows a dropdown list with multiple choices where you need to select one option in it to be able to press the next button on the page where the code is.

I want to remove the code bellow from the page entirely, but if i just delete it i get an error saying "Please select x to continue", it behaves like nothing was selected from the dropdown list.

So, could i somehow to something like `$option = "1";` to make the value of the string connected to the list always be 1 even if i remove the code ? i tried with `$shortUrlDomain = "1";` but i still get "Please select x to continue if i remove the code.

Also, if i don't remove the code i don't get the error saying

> ""Please select x to continue" of course.

**CODE:**

```
<select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
    <?php
    foreach ($shortUrlDomains AS $k => $shortUrlDomain)
    {
        // active domains only
        if($shortUrlDomain['status'] != 'enabled')
        {
            continue;
        }


        echo '<option value="' . (int) $k . '"';


        // selected option
        if ($k == (int) $_REQUEST['shortUrlDomain'])
        {
            echo 'SELECTED';
        }


        echo '>';


        echo $shortUrlDomain['domain'];


        '</option>';
    }
    echo '</optgroup>';

    ?>
</select>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
 <option value="1">someting.com
 <option value="2">someting2.com
 <option value="5">someting3.com
 <option value="8">someting4.com
 </optgroup>           
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// selected option
$selectedk = (int) $_REQUEST['shortUrlDomain'];
if ($k == $selectedk>0?$selectedk:1)
{
    echo 'SELECTED';
}
```

OR BETTER

```
// selected option
$selectedk = (int) $_REQUEST['shortUrlDomain'];
if (($selectedk && $k == $selectedk) || (!$selectedk && array_key_first($shortUrlDomains)))
{
    echo 'SELECTED';
}
```

---

This should help:

```
<select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
<?php
$forceAndShowOnlyK = 1;

foreach ($shortUrlDomains AS $k => $shortUrlDomain)
{
// active domains only
if($shortUrlDomain['status'] != 'enabled' || $k != $forceAndShowOnlyK)
{
continue;
}


echo '<option value="' . (int) $k . '"';


// selected option
if (($forceAndShowOnlyK && $k == $forceAndShowOnlyK) || (!$forceAndShowOnlyK && $k == (int) $_REQUEST['shortUrlDomain']))
{
echo 'SELECTED';
}


echo '>';
echo $shortUrlDomain['domain'];
echo '</option>';

}
echo '</optgroup>';

?>
</select>
```

Comment: Still wont work if i remove all my code and just use yours :/ originally users had to choose 1 of 4 items from the list as you can see in the "output" part above. i want to remove the list from the page and always have option 1 choose, ie the item with the "value="1"" from the output above.  I want to remove all my code and just put something like  $shortUrlDomain = "1"; in the code so i don't get the "Please select x to continue" but i think i am using the wrong string since if i remove my code seen above and just put $shortUrlDomain = "1"; i still get the error

Comment: sorry if i am bad at explaining.

Comment: use the last code and set your $k you want => $forceAndShowOnlyK = 1;

Comment: hmm i think i am still not explaining myself to good. I want to remove list all the code from <select> to </select>. When i just delete it i get "Please select x to continue" wich i dont get if i dont remove the code. when i try to press the "next" button on the page. because it acts as nothing was selected because i remove the code. so i want to have the string with the value of 1 so it always "acts" as if someone choose option one1 even if i remove everything from <select> to </select>. that's what i mean when i say i tried to remove it and just place $shortUrlDomain = "1"; there.

Comment: if you dont want to show the select dropdown, replace your <select> to </select> with this: <input type="hidden" name="shortUrlDomain" value="1">

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a validation condition somewhere else which is giving you that `Please select x to continue` message.

If you don't want to tweak it properly, you can try removing that code inside your `<select>` and add a default option like this:

```
<select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="1" selected>something.com</option>
</select>
```